# Are there theological explanations for why God allowed ambiguity to exist in Scripture?

Tags: canon, resource-request, scriptures, inspiration, schism

Doctrinal differences abound in Christianity. This is attested to by the numerous times the Church has suffered splits and given birth to different denominations, branches, and sub-branches. The question [Can somebody summarize the different “branches” of Christianity to me, and explain why they exist in the first place?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/74835/can-somebody-summarize-the-different-branches-of-christianity-to-me-and-expla) gets this point across tremendously well.

But this inevitably leads us to ask the question: **Why did God allow something like this to happen in the first place?** If we look at the root causes of the many divisions in the history of the Church, one main reason that immediately stands out is the many different ways in which the Scriptures have been interpreted throughout history. And this is nothing to be surprised about when you have Scriptures that are inherently ambiguous, lending themselves to different, and sometimes mutually exclusive, interpretations.

And just to make matters even more complicated, even before we get to interpret anything, the question about what is considered part of the canon of Scripture and what isn't is also controversial in and of itself (for evidence of this, simply take a look at the [many questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canon?tab=Votes) that have already been asked on the topic of the canon of scripture).

If God was behind the scenes inspiring and guiding the compilation of the Bible, then it follows that the existence of ambiguity in Scripture (what should be included in the canon, how Scripture should be interpreted, etc.) couldn't have been a coincidence. It had to be intentional. God, for some unknown reason, deliberately and intentionally allowed ambiguity to exist in Scripture.

Why?

---

*(*) Note: I don't intend this question to be opinion-based, so I would rather encourage answers that draw on reputable sources, e.g., the works of reputable Christian philosophers or theologians that have discussed this question before, etc. Alternatively, if a denomination has an official denominational answer to the question, it would be great to know about that too.*

---

Related questions:

- [How do proponents of Sola Scriptura choose the “correct” interpretation of a key Bible verse?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83846/how-do-proponents-of-sola-scriptura-choose-the-correct-interpretation-of-a-key)
- [How do adherents to the maxim "clearer passages interpret less clear ones" handle cases where two sets of "clear" passages contradict each other?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89211/50422)
- [Are there any denominations that give official advice on how to handle the uncertainty in their doctrines?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81069/are-there-any-denominations-that-give-official-advice-on-how-to-handle-the-uncer)

Comment: Free Will? I don't know that I can agree that the Bible is ambiguous (citation needed?). Certainly, we, as fallible humans, find ways to misinterpret it. The issue isn't so much that the Bible is unclear, but that we are sinful. Thus, the answer to your question comes down to "why does God allow Sin?".

Comment: @Matthew - are you really saying that the Bible is not ambiguous? Then how do you explain the myriads of differing opinions and interpretations? Just spend a few a minutes in https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ to see what I'm talking about ...

Comment: Exactly as in my comment; humans are really good at figuring out ways to creatively (and sometimes *deliberately*) misinterpret things. For example, Genesis 1 says that we were created on "the sixth day". *I* don't find that ambiguous, but many people read that as "the sixth unspecific-but-very-large period of time". If you're re asking why God didn't arrange for Genesis to say "the sixth day, where a day is X hours long, or X second, or <insert atomic specification>"... then, as I said, what you *really* need to ask is why does God allow Sin.

Comment: Jesus said that not everyone would understand parables, which are arguably the most lucid part of the Bible, I think you do need to do homework rather than asking questions based on suppositions.  Some Christians believe in the perspicuity of scripture others believe that only their priests have the faculties to understand and interpret it authentically, I'd imagine there are few that believe what you're describing in this question.

Comment: We all have a little voice that whispers, "Yea.  Hath God really said...?"  Jesus didn't hear that voice.

Comment: @PeterTurner Perspecuity doesn't mean that all Scripture is unambiguous, it means that the things necessary for salvation are unambiguous.

Comment: If the bible is unambiguous and the reason we misinterpret it is sin, then how is it possible that individuals who were sanctified (one of the conditions of sanctification is to be without sin) can have different interpretations?

Comment: @Codosaur I think it's because we are *being* sanctified.  No one gets there on this side of the dirt.  "If anyone says he is without sin he is a liar and the truth is not in him."

Comment: Then basically, the conditions for sanctification cannot ever truly be met - by anyone? Wouldn't that nullify the validity of the entire endeavor?

Comment: @Matthew - just in case you were still in doubt about the ambiguity of scripture, [check this out](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/59617/where-their-worm-does-not-die-and-the-fire-is-not-quenched-is-jesus-des).

Comment: i wonder if this is more of a philosophical than theological thing. ambiguity exists in scripture for the same reason ambiguity exists elsewhere: people are ambiguous. you read a maths textbook, and there's often ambiguity. why should scripture be any different? i expect scripture should even be more ambiguous, where it seems like you except scripture would be less ambiguous than a maths textbook right?

Comment: @BCLC - there is ambiguity in math textbooks, but eventually you will always arrive at the same conclusion that the theorem stated, provided that you do your math properly. There is no one questioning the validity of any well-known mathematical theorem. Nobody questions the validity of the Pythagorean theorem, the multiple proofs that the square root of two is an irrational number, etc. You don't see the same level of unshakable consensus in doctrinal matters. I discussed about this in an [earlier question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/81069/50422).

Comment: interesting. thanks.

Comment: More than one reason, some are related to what is being said in Revelation 1:1, that it was a message presented in signs to Jesus' slaves (same as in Matthew 13:10-15). Another reason is from what Jesus foretold, that eventually the Devil would sow seeds of "imitation Christians" into the field (Matthew 13:24-30, Matthew 13:36-40). As a result some religious organizations for centuries tried to keep the Bible in a dead language, even persecuting those who worked on translating it (and even though in 1st century what was written was written in contemporary languages available to majority).

Comment: Alternatively, you could say that God did a remarkable job at getting a unified book to the world about the one most important human form to ever walk the earth, and much more. By **far** the most popular book in world history and largely identical across millenia and continents. / Secondly, at least some, if not much or most, of the division has a clear winner where one side is simply denying that book. I realized this on a whole new level when I heard Doug Willians say, “you walk into an orthodox church and ask are they praying to pictures. And they are. Well, the bible says dont do that.”

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Matthew 13, Jesus reveals that it is God's will that some people understand and others be confused:

> 11 He replied, “Because the knowledge of the secrets of the kingdom of
> heaven has been given to you, but not to them. 12 Whoever has will be
> given more, and they will have an abundance. Whoever does not have,
> even what they have will be taken from them. 13 This is why I speak to
> them in parables:
>
> “Though seeing, they do not see;
> though hearing, they do not hear or understand.
>
> 14 In them is fulfilled the prophecy of Isaiah:
>
> “‘You will be ever hearing but never understanding;
> you will be ever seeing but never perceiving. 15 For this people’s heart has become calloused;
> they hardly hear with their ears,
> and they have closed their eyes. Otherwise they might see with their eyes,
> hear with their ears,
> understand with their hearts and turn, and I would heal them.’
>
> 16 But blessed are your eyes because they see, and your ears because
> they hear. 17 For truly I tell you, many prophets and righteous people
> longed to see what you see but did not see it, and to hear what you
> hear but did not hear it.

Jesus is here repeating sentiments found in Psalms 115 & 135 and in Isaiah 6.

Furthermore, Proverbs 2 tells us that wisdom only comes to people who make a long study of Scripture.

> My son, if you accept my words
> and store up my commands within you, 2 turning your ear to wisdom
> and applying your heart to understanding— 3 indeed, if you call out for insight
> and cry aloud for understanding, 4 and if you look for it as for silver
> and search for it as for hidden treasure, 5 then you will understand the fear of the Lord
> and find the knowledge of God. 6 For the Lord gives wisdom;
> from his mouth come knowledge and understanding. 7 He holds success in store for the upright,
> he is a shield to those whose walk is blameless, 8 for he guards the course of the just
> and protects the way of his faithful ones.
>
> 9 Then you will understand what is right and just
> and fair—every good path. 10 For wisdom will enter your heart,
> and knowledge will be pleasant to your soul. 11 Discretion will protect you,
> and understanding will guard you.

You have to prove you believe, that God's word matters to you and is precious before such wisdom is entrusted to you. The preceding words from Proverbs indicate that your search for wisdom must engage your mind and verbal faculties - calling out, your heart and emotions - crying aloud, and your hands (or habits of behavior) - searching as for treasure. In reciprocal fashion, God responds to your mind (from his mouth comes knowledge), heart (wisdom enters your heart), and the guidance of your actions (he protects your ways).

As Jesus said, the Kingdom of Heaven is one that grows like a mustard seed (Matthew 13 & 17). It does not start out full size. You begin with small understanding and if you cultivate it patiently, you end up with great understanding.

Thus the Church is filled with people at every level of understanding, and some charlatans with no understanding.

In the last three years, through an increased thirst for the reading of scripture, I have learned more than in the previous two decades combined. What that tells me is that even after thirty years of being a Christian, I have much to learn. If it is true for individuals like me, it is also true for denominations and other groupings of Christians. In my study of Ecclesiastes 3, I have found two interesting things. First, the 28 times (a time to be born , a time to die, etc) describe the phases we go through as we grow from infancy to adulthood, with the final time being peace. Second, these times also describe the history of Israel and the Church as God's people corporately grow from infancy to maturity. We are still not all the way there, but we will get there.

Comment: I wish I could upvote several times!  This is gold!  Especially damaging, I think, are people who are so caught up in their own politics (church leadership included), that they give the Scriptures that they *claim* to follow, a bad reputation.  Their observers still believe the claim, and therefore conclude that following The Bible must make you that bad.  Why pursue something that has that result?  Sadly, most of them never come back to review that flawed logic.  (their examples did NOT in fact follow The Bible like they claimed)

Comment: +1 One can sell out to a "theology" and walk off of the path.

Comment: Also consider: "*“Whom will he teach knowledge?
And whom will he make to understand the message?
Those just weaned from milk?
Those just drawn from the breasts?
For precept must be upon precept, precept upon precept,
Line upon line, line upon line,
Here a little, there a little.”*" — [(Isaiah 28:9–10)](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/isa/28/10/s_707010)
And: "*… they received the word with all readiness, and searched the Scriptures daily to find out whether these things were so.*" — [(Acts 17:11)](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/act/17/11/s_1035011)
"Blindly obey" is more OT.

Comment: @MikeBordenYes, all disciples can hear and must hear the Truth, like what happened to Saul. More than hearing, God cause him to get blind for him to see the Truth about who Jesus is. But, after the Truth had been revealed to us, like St.Paul we cannot proclaim on our won or form ministry of our own. In order for the Spirit of Truth to work in our ministry, we all must follow what St.Paul did, by "shaking the hands" of the Three Pillars in Galatians2:9-10 before he can start proclaiming the Truth, so that the promise of Jesus in John16:12-14 will be upon the likes of St.Paul.

Comment: @RayButterworth John16:12-14 is a unique promise, and all must realize this before proclaiming the Truth. St.Paul "shake the hands" of the Three Pillars before preaching the Truth, in Vatican II era, this is called Ecumenism, and even extended to Non-Christian thru fraternal agreement. All must preach and witness the Truth united to Peter Magisterium in order that the Spirit of Truth can lead us united as one. -John17:20-22

Comment: Your summary of Proverbs 2:1-11 that it “tells us that wisdom only comes to people who make a long study of Scripture.” was liberal at best. If I had assigned that to a student and said summarize that for us, I would hope they wouldnt come up with that. The rest of the answer was great.

Comment: @AlBrown - Sorry to disappoint. That passage in Proverbs is so precious to me that I have devoted many pages to describing it in my books. Summarizing something so rich in a few words is challenging. I will amend what I have written to do it better justice.

Comment: @PaulChernoch apologies about being so critical, was more related to me than it, so my fault

Comment: @AlBrown - No need to apologize. I have outlined an entire book which I hope to write next year whose subject is principles that may be found in that passage. I need to be able to explain it cogently and carefully. This is practice.

Comment: Thanks. Was mostly talking about the wording of my comment but thats great  , I have two issues with many modern christians, even ones I otherwise like, such as macarthur and sproul and that bunch: they end-up implying that logos means bible and so run around making claims about what the bible says about the bible, that arent true. Secondly and relatedly, they worship the bible rather than the living Christ and our living God. (By living Christ i obviously dont mean human Jesus). None of this is to dis bible-reading, but the dry worship of knowledge isnt “It” and can even cause pride.

Comment: 2/3 Thats why translating “My son, if you accept my words and store up my commands within you, 2 turning your ear to wisdom and applying your heart to understanding— 3 indeed, if you call out for insight and cry aloud for understanding,” as “If you read the Bible”. Even “if you accept my words and store up my commands within you”, which is only part of the suggested behavior, doesnt exactly say “if you read the bible”.

Comment: 3/3 Accepting words, storing up commands, merely means if you accept what Im saying. (Or maybe even “what im saying now” but i’ll even grant it as not that). I do think a lot are missing the fulness by making it mostly an academic endeavor: Knowing about God. Whereas knowing God is different. I heard a preacher say he talked to another preacher who said “I found Christ” - after ten years of preaching, he finally found Christ. So one can read the bible without Christ having actually come. Again, not to dis reading the bible NOR question what you said it has recently done for you. I believe you

Comment: @AlBrown - My reference point for the totality of the ideal engagement with the word is Jesus’ parable of the soils. The first challenge is the mind accepting truth, the second is the heart receiving comfort but also experiencing proper fear, and the third is the hand (action) taking up habits that display the right priorities. Mind, heart & hand. (Of course a book by John MacArthur helped me survive one of the most traumatic years of my life. I no longer regard all writers and thinkers who have worthy and helpful things to say as infallible.)

Comment: I definitely believe the Bible to be written by the HS, the only book that has. What Im saying is that Prov 2 and the parable of the sower dont say “bible” they say Truth, and they say Logos (translated as “Word”, not because of bad translators but because of no English word thats close). Yes the Bible is a source, but it is not the same as “wisdom” so we cant say the bible is the only source of wisdom if the Logos is. God is the source. People hear “word” which may have come from Logos or rehma and hear bible. Christ is the answer. Anyway thanks for reading and replies and God bless

Answer (score 10):

#### Why God allows ambiguities and what He does to help us

1. Most denominations hold that the Holy Spirit inspires not only the Biblical book authors but also

   - the **Individual Bible reader**, and/or
   - the **Church Councils** (producing canon, creeds, documents), and/or
   - the **Church teaching authority** (such as the Catholic magisterium, producing guidelines)

   so that **ambiguities are reduced**, or in rare cases eliminated.
2. How we approach the Bible is critical.  If we read the Bible merely as history, as "true myth", as literature, as science book, or as a collection of ancient documents of a faith community, we will receive no help beyond scholarly literature to resolve the ambiguities remaining in the text. But, the faithful read the Bible as MORE than history, literature, and ancient document:

   - We also read the Bible as the **Word of God** where we **listen to what the Holy Spirit wants to say** to us in our heart through the passage we are reading.
   - We also ask God **questions coming from our present need & specific circumstances**, triggered by our identification with the Bible character, a scene, God's promise, Jesus's saying, a psalm, a prophecy, etc. in the passage.

   Thus, after availing ourselves of the best that commentaries can provide, in reading devotionally the ambiguity usually **ceases to be relevant** because we read more as a means for God to speak to us, convict us of our sins, comfort us, inspire us, etc.  Good commentaries will be *honest* by giving us credible historical, or denominationally-informed options, but leaving some ambiguities intact instead of inserting themselves stealthily.  While ambiguities remain, we survive by **trusting God the person** instead of worrying over our gap-filled *idea of God*.
3. All denominations admit that their theologies are necessarily incomplete, because the Bible does not reveal everything about God.  AT THE SAME TIME all denominations say that the Bible has **enough truths that we need to know for our salvation**, and that the Holy Spirit helps us to overcome doubts caused by ambiguities so we can trust God's promises.  Seen from this perspective, **ambiguities are not devastating**.
4. Yes, different interpretations lead to different conflicting doctrines.  Let's not pretend they don't exist.  Like the OP, naturally we ask God: **WHY**?  After 2,000 year history maybe God wants to teach us one or more of these lessons:

   - God doesn't want to be reduced to a particular system of theology that one group can use to oppress another as we saw in the history of wars over denominations.  In other words, God wants to teach us **humility and charity** toward believers of different stripes.
   - Most denominations teach that the Bible is God's means of *partially* revealing Himself (in addition to Jesus Christ and general revelation), as God intends to remain *hidden* to **preserve people's free will** so that only those who are willing to open their hearts's door can receive His illuminating presence, His saving grace, His wisdom, and His blessing.  Therefore, God may have left the ambiguities for this purpose.
   - God wants to provide different ways to worship and approach him, working through his Holy Spirit simultaneously through several LEGITIMATE denominations and letting history to build up several traditions to **manifest His glory within multiple communities of faith like different colors of a rainbow**.  For example, one tradition emphasizes sacraments.  Another emphasizes icons and beautiful liturgies.  Another emphasizes the Bible as the sole means to engage God personally.  Another emphasizes loving action in the world.
   - Especially in non-Western countries, new theologies are emerging to take into account non-Western cultural contexts.  Some mission theologians have seen Western-style theologies as not sufficiently developed to address questions that these new cultures bring to the faith.  While this can be alarming to some, others look at this as *opportunities* to manifest God's saving glory in a new way, while being careful to maintain certain orthodoxy of the faith against false teachings such as prosperity gospel.  Maybe these ambiguities are left **for new cultures to plug into the Kingdom**.

#### How a denomination helps resolve most ambiguities

Those who accept the role of Church Councils and/or Magisterium in one's reading of the Bible will use their recommended guidelines to give us better certainties about God by narrowing the ambiguities significantly.  For examples, they believe that the Holy Spirit inspired those who produced the Westminster Confession or inspires those currently serving as the Catholic Magisterium.

Even those who reject the relevance of church council or magisterium to guide their reading of the Bible, such as many "non-denominational" evangelicals, they usually STILL use a few principles to resolve "ambiguity" such as adherence to the practice of [Inductive Bible Study](https://www.logos.com/how-to/inductive-bible-study).  They will appeal to several Bible verses as evidence that the inductive bible study method is sanctioned by the Holy Spirit.  Using this method usually helps resolve most ambiguities.

Below are some common areas related to Bible interpretation that denominations address to reduce ambiguities.  Different denominations provide their own answer although there are many overlaps:

1. **How the canon is formed**: although most denominations consider the canon "closed" since the early church fathers era they differ on the criteria used to select the books
2. **The level of inerrancy**: to word level, concept level, etc.
3. **What topics are inspired**: some say matters of faith are more inspired than things that are in the domain of science, others say all are equally inspired and the Bible has a better track record on science than atheist scientists, etc.
4. **Whether the Holy Spirit inspires only certain readers**: guaranteeing inspiration only for the elect, or for those to read through the eyes of faith, or for everyone (believers or not)
5. **The role of church dogmas and/or tradition in guiding interpretation**: examples: [rule of faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Faith), [Catholic guidance](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/print-edition/the-limits-of-scripture-interpretation), [sola scriptura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura), etc.
6. **Hermeneutical principles to interpret the Bible properly**:

   - whether context is book by book, author by author, or using the whole canon to guide the interpretation of a verse
   - how NT interprets OT
   - whether allegorical reading is allowed
   - proper use of ancient customs, myths, literary forms, and languages
   - external principles used: covenant / dispensation scheme, salvation history, source / form / redaction criticism, documentary hypothesis, etc.
   - the role of text criticism and authorized translation
   - Barthian style hermeneutic (i.e. Bible is 100% human text but the reader is given individual inspiration directly by the Holy Spirit)

#### C.S. Lewis advice to cope with the reality of conflicting doctrines

In the Preface to his book [Mere Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mere_Christianity) C.S. Lewis likens each denomination to a **room** (representing the community of believers for that denomination).  Each room is connected to an empty **hallway** (representing the perspective of a believer who is choosing which denomination to trust, i.e. struggling with the ambiguities).  All the rooms and the hallway are in a big **house** (representing God's Kingdom where all who answer the call of God to trust Him live).  In the context of this question, each believer in the hallway can grow in faith by joining a denomination (or a local non-denominational church / faith community) which helps the believer resolve some ambiguities *collectively* while having charity for those who resolve the ambiguities differently in another room.

Here is the quote:

> I hope no reader will suppose that 'mere' Christianity is here put forward as an alternative to the creeds of the existing communions — as if a man could adopt it in preference to Congregationalism or Greek Orthodoxy or anything else. It is more like a hall out of which doors open into several rooms. If I can bring anyone into that hall, I have done what I attempted. But it is in the rooms, not the hall, that there are fires and chairs and meals. The hall is a place to wait in, a place from which to try the various doors, not a place to live in. For that purpose the worst of the rooms (whichever that may be) is, I think preferable. It is true that some people may find they have to wait in the hall for a considerable time, while others feel certain almost at once which door they must knock at. I do not know why there is this difference, but I am sure God keeps no one waiting unless He sees that it is good for him to wait. When you do get into the room you will find that the long wait has done some kind of good which you would not have had otherwise. But you must regard it as waiting, not as camping. You must keep on praying for light: and, of course, even in the hall, you must begin trying to obey the rules which are common to the whole house. And above all you must be asking which door is the true one; not which pleases you best by its paint and paneling. In plain language, the question should never be: "Do I like that kind of service?" but **"Are these doctrines true: Is holiness here? Does my conscience move me towards this? Is my reluctance to knock at this door due to my pride, or my mere taste, or my personal dislike of this particular door-keeper?**"

> When you have reached your own room, **be kind to those who have chosen different doors and to those who are still in the hall**. If they are wrong they need your prayers all the more; and if they are your enemies, then you are under orders to pray for them. This is one of the rules common to the whole house.

Comment: "some say matters of faith are more inspired than things that are in the domain of science". Yes, and conversely, others say the Bible has a better track record on science than atheist scientists.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks.  I added it.  I also add a whole new section to address the WHY.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I noticed your question edit yesterday and after thinking about it I added a significant portion to my answer for addressing your WHY question.  I try to be mindful of multiple legitimate denominations so my answer will be applicable to all of them.  Let me know if there are remaining areas to address.

Answer (score 5):

One part might be that God wants to **reveal hearts**.  A determined critic can *always* find a creative way to misunderstand.  In politics for instance, it's surprising how creative people can be at misrepresenting, spinning, and "misunderstanding" something.  God could have spent an inordinate amount of space in His Word trying to "correct" all the millions of potential "misunderstandings"; but that would make the Bible sound extremely defensive and very jumbled, and very little of what God really wanted to communicate would come across.

And so I believe God wrote the Bible with some anti-tampering built in, and spending *some* time addressing critics and questions, but with *most* of the space dedicated to delivering the healthy spiritual "milk" and "meat" that we really need.  Also, many passages in the Bible are deeply spiritual; those who haven't been born again cannot understand them (I Corinthians 2:13ff), but only through the Holy Spirit's help.  In any case, the attitude in which we approach the Bible reveals a lot about our hearts.  Thus the Bible also becomes "a discerner of the thoughts and intents of the heart" (Hebrews 4:12).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for expressing *exactly* what I was trying (without nearly so much success) to convey.

Comment: Yeah that was great. Thanks. I heard a christian radio tech and theologian say if you want to prevent a signal from getting scrambled you repeat in multiple locations and different orders.

Answer (score 5):

The Best Answer was chosen before I read this question (within 24 hours of it being posted) and, having read all the answers, I wish to point out that the scriptures of the Bible tell us exactly why many parts seem ambiguous (and thus why no end of different interpretations are made.) There is no need to go seeking Christian philosophers, theologians, or denominational views.

It is a unique collection of writings inspired by the Holy Spirit, with a precise use of words that is staggering. It is also a mystery book because it contains both mysteries and secrets that are only revealed by the Holy Spirit to those sincerely searching its pages to learn the mind of Christ, for the entire collection points to Christ.  The Bible itself warns readers that their view of God is what determines their understanding, or their misunderstanding of God and his word:

> "To the faithful you show yourself faithful; to those with integrity
> you show integrity. To the pure you show yourself pure but to the
> wicked you show yourself hostile. You rescue the humble, but your eyes
> watch the proud and humiliate them." - 2 Samuel 22:26-28 NLT "For the
> word of God is alive and powerful. It is sharper than the sharpest
> two-edged sword, cutting between soul and spirit, between joint and
> marrow. It exposes our innermost thoughts and desires. Nothing in all
> creation is hidden from his sight." - Hebrews 4:12-13 NLT

Further, the Christian apostle, Peter, wrote of Paul,

> "Bear in mind that our Lord's patience means salvation, just as our
> dear brother Paul also wrote to you with the wisdom that God gave him.
> He writes the same way in all his letters, speaking in them of these
> matters. His letters contain some things that are hard to understand,
> which ignorant and unstable people distort, as they do the other
> Scriptures, to their own destruction." (Peter 3:15-16)

We are tested by God every time we read his word, as to whether we are pure in motive and humble in spirit, seeking his truth or if we are out to be critical of God and his holy word. The latter are on the highway to hell but if they humbled themselves under God's mighty hand, they could be spared. This means that those who read the Bible thinking it is ambiguous and, therefore, because they don't get the clear meaning they think it ought to convey they are free to criticize it as not inspired of God, are being judged by God even as they think such thoughts. They need not expect further enlightenment or even meaningful clarity of thought.

Comment: @ Spirit Realm Investigator if you could contain your enthusiasm for choosing Best Answer so quickly - waiting a couple of more days, perhaps - you may get more answers. But rarely will an answer be posted after Best Answer has been appointed. On this site it is usually beneficial to give a question at least 2 days, preferably a week or more, to garner a selection of answers!

Comment: Point taken. I temporarily removed the check mark from the accepted answer. Let's see how things unfold for a couple of days.

Answer (score 3):

If we can agree that such confusions and contentions are undesirable, as [Ephesians chapter 4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians+4&version=KJV) strongly suggests, then the question of why God would allow it simply reduces to the old question of [The Problem of Evil.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theodicy)

The most common answer given by various Christian denominations is that God considers free will paramount; that without the ability to make wrong choices, doing the right thing is meaningless, and that therefore God removing the possibility of error would be causing an even greater evil than he has eliminated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your argument. 1) How can having doctrinal confusions be **better** than having no doctrinal confusions? How does the Church benefit from having doctrinal confusions? 2) Are you saying that the reason why some denominations that have the wrong doctrines is because they are evil?

Comment: I'm saying that having doctrinal confusions is better than having no free will. Subtle but important difference there.

Comment: What about having free will **and** no doctrinal confusions? Are you suggesting that it's impossible to have free will and no confusions in a topic? What about math? Are there any confusions regarding the correctness of the proofs of mathematical theorems?

Comment: I believe it's impossible to have free will and be guaranteed of no confusions in a topic.  You don't need math to prove this; just a bit of basic logic: if people are free to make mistakes and wrong choices, and people are capable of interpreting doctrine, then they're free to either mistakenly or maliciously misinterpret doctrine, and then to pass on those incorrect interpretations to others.

Comment: Sure, but you can still mitigate the problem by very carefully writing unambiguous statements. Surely someone can get confused while trying to understand the proof of a mathematical theorem, but after careful inspection they will eventually realize what their mistake was and come to the same conclusion that the theorem originally stated. You don't see this in the case of doctrines.

Comment: People are free to make math mistakes also, yet you don't see the same level of controversy in math as you see in Christianity regarding doctrinal differences. When was the last time that [the proof that the square root of two is an irrational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality) was challenged?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator funny you should mention that specific example; it's rather infamous as the subject of a mathematician's dispute that ended with the one proving it being put to death because the concept of irrational numbers offended Pythagoras's dogmatic belief that irrational numbers do not exist.

Comment: I would need a citation for that one, but anyways, my point still stands. A dogmatic visceral reaction is not based on logic and reason. At that time they didn't have proofs. Now we have the proofs, unambiguous proofs that anyone can verify. You don't see people attacking each other today because they do not agree with existing proofs of the irrationality of the square root of two, or any other proofs of well-known theorems for that matter. In contrast, you have hundreds of years of the same old debates in Christianity, that never reach a consensus.

Comment: "At that time they didn't have proofs."  Yes, actually they did.  That was the problem.  The proof undermined Pythagoras's dogma, so Pythagoras had him executed as a heretic.  (Strange as it sounds, the guy was basically running a cult of mathematics-worship.)

Comment: If something is ambiguous then interpretation isn't about free-will. Someone could want to do the most good but take the incorrect interpretation. The bible is there as guidance as to what the right way to live and worship is - I don't see how this being clear removes free-will.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer to this is that where there are ambiguities--true ambiguities--the answer to the burning question is not necessary for us to know. The doctrinal disagreements are generally based on doctrines which are clear in Scripture, but which are interpreted in false ways by many.

The Bible says nothing of anything being God-breathed (inspired) except the Scripture itself. Inspired readers, Church authorities, etc. are baseless, at least in the Bible.

Comment: *The doctrinal disagreements are generally based on doctrines which are clear in Scripture, but which are interpreted in false ways by many* - do you know any denomination that gets most of its interpretations right?

Answer (score 2):

You ask for answers to draw on the works of reputable Christian theologians, so where better to quote from than the words of Jesus Christ when he addressed a bunch of learned theologians of his day?

Those scholars found Jesus perplexing, and they could not grasp his testimony nor determine the source of his miraculous powers. In John's gospel account, the whole of chapter 5 details their objections to what he was saying and doing, accusing him of being ambiguous. They were demanding that he spell out clearly who he was, where he was from, and why he was doing and saying so many things that didn't make sense to them. So, Jesus told them straight:

> "Search the scriptures; for in them ye think ye have eternal life:
> and they are they which testify of me. And ye will not come to me,
> that ye might have life... For had ye believed Moses, ye would have
> believe me: for he wrote of me. But if ye believe not his writings,
> how shall ye believe my words?"  (John 5:39-40 & 46-47)

They found the scriptures about Christ ambiguous because they had not searched them to find out about Christ. This meant that, despite all their protestations to the contrary, they had not believed Moses. Well, pointed out Jesus, if you don't believe what Moses wrote, you're never going to believe me. And so he left them to it; blind guides leading the blind (Mat. 15:14). So much for the learned, respected theologians of the day.

This shows that, in order to understand what the Bible says, we must believe all of it (whether our understanding is clear as yet, or not) and as we delve diligently into it, sincerely seeking to learn about Christ in it, the ambiguities will begin to melt.

It is the same when Jesus gave his account of the rich man dying and finding himself in torments in hell, and Lazarus finding himself in bliss. When the once-rich man protested that his brothers on earth would believe if someone returned from the dead to warn them of hell, he was told, "If they hear not Moses and the prophets, neither will they be persuaded though one rose from the dead" (Luke 16:20-31). This means that those who pick and choose what they will believe in the scriptures are just never going to understand. The writings will be full of ambiguity, apparently contradictory stuff, if not plain nonsense. And the more difficulty they find trying to understand scripture, the less they will bother with it.

On the contrary, those who have deep reverence for God's written word, will go deeper and deeper into it out of a heartfelt desire to "find" Christ in it, equally in the Old Testament as the New. Christ is the key to understanding the scriptures. He appears ambiguous to those who don't believe him to be the Son of God, but to those who have discovered him to be such, his words are sprinkled like diamonds all over the Bible, from the start to the finish, for Christ IS the Word of God.

**There, then, is the theological explanation straight from the words of the greatest theologian there has ever been.** They form a screening device to sift out those who sincerely desire to understand the Word of God, those who will not be stumbled by seeming ambiguities and puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

#### Because the Church is the Body of Christ, and the body has many parts for different purposes.

Quoting from the book of [1 Corinthians, Chapter 12](https://biblehub.com/bsb/1_corinthians/12.htm):

> The body is a unit, though it is composed of many parts. And although its parts are many, they all form one body. So it is with Christ. For in one Spirit we were all baptized into one body, whether Jews or Greeks, slave or free, and we were all given one Spirit to drink.
>
> ...
>
> If the whole body were an eye, where would the sense of hearing be? If the whole body were an ear, where would the sense of smell be?
>
> But in fact, God has arranged the members of the body, every one of them, according to His design. If they were all one part, where would the body be? As it is, there are many parts, but one body.

The different denominations of the Church are like different parts of the body, working to support the mission of God and his Kingdom in different ways, just like the different parts of the body assist you in different ways when you perform tasks in day-to-day life.

So, the logical conclusion for why God had the Bible written in such a way so that its interpretations could give rise to differences in opinion about its meaning, it's so that those differences in interpretation can give rise to different groups that serve His will in different ways.

Answer (score -3):

*Are there theological explanations for why God allowed the existence of ambiguity in Scripture?*

**The answer is Yes.** And that was the purpose why Jesus founded His Church on the rock. And the Church will be the guardian and pillars of Truth.

> And I tell you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build my church, and the gates of Hades will not overcome it. I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven; whatever you bind on earth will be bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth will be loosed in heaven.”(Matthew16:18-19

> if I am delayed, you will know how people ought to conduct themselves in God’s household, which is the church of the living God, the pillar and foundation of the truth.(1Timothy3:15)

We can see clearly that Jesus had chosen the twelve Apostles to teach them and gave them authority and promised them the guidance of the Spirit of Truth, take note, Jesus promised them not the "gifts of the Holy Spirit" but the "Spirit of Truth" who also personifies the "another Advocate". And Jesus called His Apostles "friends".

> *No longer do I call you servants, for a servant does not understand what his master is doing. But I have called you friends, because everything I have learned from My Father I have made known to you.* (John1:15)

All Christians and Catholic faithful can read and understand the bible and even interprets it according to the gifts of the Holy Spirit or according to their inspiration and faith-lived experiences. But, Christian and Catholic individuals cannot claimed that their personal interpretation is the Truth, that's the key difference from the Apostles.

The Apostles were given the power to bind their teachings and interpretation, while individual followers or disciples has no teaching authority.

> *"Truly, I say to you, whatever you bind on earth shall be bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth shall be loosed in heaven."* ... Matthew 18:18

But, Peter was especial because of the this two passages Matthew16:19 and an assurance that his faith will not fail in Luke22:32.

> *I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven; whatever you bind on earth will be[a] bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth will be[b] loosed in heaven.”*

> *But I have prayed for you, Simon, that your faith may not fail. And when you have turned back, strengthen your brothers.”*

Actually, Peter's faith failed by denying Christ three times, and also the remaining Apostles who made their oath along with Peter that they will not deny Jesus the Son of Man during the Last Supper ceremony. Judas was already gone when they made the oath to Jesus Christ in the gospel of Matthew chpater26.

Peter was able to rise-up as he was led to seek the help of the Theotokos the Advocate or Advocata in the First century Christian Tradition. Peter was consoled by the Blessed Virgin Mary, and after that Peter consoled all the Apostles who somehow also deny Jesus by hiding in the hour of His passion and death, Luke22:32 was fulfilled as Peter was able to console and strengthen the Apostles, his brethren.

In closing, *is there an ambiguity in scriptures?* **Yes**. *Did God purposely allow the ambiguity?* **Yes**, because God wanted to establish His Church and Authority, so that all ambiguity can be settled by Church Authority as the Final Authority because they were chosen by God, they were taught by Jesus, they were ordained by Jesus and promised the guidance of the Spirit of Truth and the another Advocate that were not promise to any individual Christian and even to Pastors.